# Let $Z$ be standard normal can we find a pdf of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ where $Z_1=Z \cdot 1_{S},Z_2=Z \cdot 1_{S^c}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ and let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable. 
Let
\begin{align}
Z_1&=Z \cdot 1_{S},\\
Z_2&=Z \cdot 1_{S^c},
\end{align}
where $1_S$ is an indicator function and $S=[-a,a]$ for some $a>0$.

Can we find the distribution of  ${Z_1}$ and  $(Z_1,Z_2)$ and $Z_1 |Z_2$?

Thanks.

Comment: They are the same as PDF of Z, but multiplied by an Indicator and a normalizer constant...

Comment: @LeilaHatami Can you show it to me?  Also, what about $f_{Z_1,Z_2}$??

Comment: These have no PDF since each $Z_i$ is partly discrete, partly continuous.

Comment: @LeilaHatami No.

Comment: @Did Thank you. I reformulated my answer.

Comment: @Did Was it true for discrete distributions?

Comment: The distribution of $Z_1$ is a barycenter of the Dirac mass at $0$ and of the distribution of $Z$ conditioned by $Z\in S$. If you want a formula, $$dP_{Z_1}(z)=P(Z\notin S)\delta_0(dz)+f_Z(z)\mathbf 1_{z\in S}dz$$ The distribution of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ is concentrated on the coordinate axes of the plane, writing it in details is cumbersome. The distribution of $Z_1$ conditional on $Z_2=z_2$ with $z_2\ne0$ is the Dirac mass at $0$. The distribution of $Z_1$ conditional on $Z_2=0$ is the distribution of $Z$ conditioned by $Z\in S$, whose PDF is $$\frac{f_Z(z)\mathbf 1_{z\in S}}{P(Z\in S)}$$

Comment: @Did What is the distribution of $Z$ condition on $Z_1$ or $Z_2$?

Comment: New problem? Then ask a new question! By the way, would it be outrageous to enquire whether you got anything at all from my previous detailed comment?

Comment: @Did Yes, I think that understand  what $P_{Z_1}$ is. It was surprising to me that it is not continuous. So, I should really post a question about $Z$ given $Z_1$ as a new question?